# Search for an object with a specific value in an array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, nosql-aggregation

I have an array of objects in my document which resides in a collection in MongoDB. And, it looks like the following

```
"tracking": [{
    "track_id" : "abcd",
    "timestamp" : 1604581360,
    "status" : "approved",
    "category" : "containers",
    "time_of_activity" : "23:11",
    "date_of_activity" : "03-Oct-20"
}, {...}, ...]
```

I want to search for an object on this array where the track_id of the object is `abcd`

I am having a hard time writing a Mongo Aggregation for the same. Can anyone please show me a way, to how this can be achieved using a Mongo Aggregation query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query embedded documents inside an array using [find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) as below:

> db.collection.find({"tracking.track_id": "abcd"})

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tGbRwnOi5_c)